# libncurses.so.5 : Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I tried to debug a C application with Eclipse using GDB but I got the following error:

```
Error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install `libncurses5` but it's already installed.

Should I change the location of this package? any idea?

---

This is what I got after running `locate libncurses`.

```
# locate libncurses
/home/sina/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,any,any,any,libncurses5-dbg,page,1,helpful,,187a06d92ba0b73dd50444293b7cab16
/home/sina/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,quantal,any,libncurses5-dbg,page,1,helpful,,e8f56bcf979e4c966af1cf8fcfb46b89
/home/sina/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,ubuntu,raring,any,libncurses5-dbg,page,1,helpful,,9e8b7962287c629e99b01502879a8f35
/home/sina/Downloads/libncurses5-dbg_5.9+20130608-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9
/usr/lib/libncurses++_g.a
/usr/lib/libncurses_g.a
/usr/lib/debug/libncurses.so.5
/usr/lib/debug/libncurses.so.5.9
/usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
/usr/lib/debug/lib32/libncurses.so.5.9
/usr/lib/debug/lib32/libncursesw.so.5.9
/usr/lib/debug/usr/libx32/libncurses.so.5.9
/usr/lib/debug/usr/libx32/libncursesw.so.5.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5-dbg
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5-dev
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw5
/var/cache/apt/archives/libncurses5-dbg_5.9-10ubuntu4_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5-dbg.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5-dbg.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5-dbg.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5-dev.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.symbols
```

Comment: what does 'locate libncurses' return on the command line?

Comment: Are you trying to debug a 32-bit application?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the debugging symbols for debugging applications:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dbg
```

The `-dbg` means debug which is the symbols your are lacking.

Comment: I did install that package...still get the same error. That's truly bizarre!  None of the target programs use the ncurses library and in fact it is not in the target file system.  I have no clue why the debugger would be trying to load libncurses.

Comment: gdb itself depends on libncurses5 - it's probably not trying to load it for your target (and probably doesn't need libncurses5-dev or libncurses5-dbg). You could try `ldd $(which gdb)` to see if anything looks broken - or purge and reinstall gdb itself maybe?

Comment: root@sina-linux:~# ldd $(which gdb)
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff609fe000)
 libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f84ae320000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f84ae11c000)
 libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f84adefa000)
 libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f84adcd2000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f84adabb000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f84ad7b5000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f84ad598000)

Comment: libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f84ad069000)
 libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f84ace3f000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f84aca76000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f84ae57d000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f84ac873000)

Comment: make any sense?

Comment: No, none. You should edit your question instead for adding more information.

Comment: @PeterMortensen you need the correct number of the ncurses library, since it's standard Debian practice that shared modules have their own namespace.